# first line problem in nicedit ?

Tags: javascript, nicedit

Hello i have small problem with nicedit editor

the problem is

the first line is can not be affected !

example :

i writed ( asdad ) in the first line of the textarea box

i marked it and clicked on ( center align )

it's should go to the center of the box

see this picture

[image]

this problem is only in first line ..

others is work fine

The problem is only in firefox !

i am using firefox 3..... and i see this problem !

my code is

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
<textarea cols=40 rows=10></textarea>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem. And we are not alone:) It is nicEditor's bug http://nicedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=364&p=848&#p848. And looks like it isn't fixed yet.

I've solved this bug by using TinyMCE-editor :) And if you are not tied with nicEditor I would suggest to look on TinyMCE.

I hope it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a solution for this.
The problem is the first line that is not in a div.
This will fix it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nicEdit-main').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
        nicEditFirstLinePatch();
    });
});
```

and

```
function nicEditFirstLinePatch(){
    function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
                && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            range.collapse(false);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(el);
            textRange.collapse(false);
            textRange.select();
        }
    }
    textNode=$('.nicEdit-main').contents().filter(function(){ 
        return this.nodeType == 3; 
    })[0];
    $('.nicEdit-main').attr('id','toHandle');
    if(textNode){
        var newNode = document.createElement('div');
        var newNodeContent = document.createTextNode(textNode.nodeValue);
        newNode.appendChild(newNodeContent);
        var parentNode=document.getElementById('toHandle');
        parentNode.replaceChild(newNode,textNode);
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(newNode,0);  
    }
    if(document.getElementById('toHandle').children.length==1){
        placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById("toHandle"));
    }
}
```

It works fine on Chrome 55.0.2883.87. I think it's crossbrowser but I'm not sure. however it is a good start :)